# Special box -activated when clicked, deactivated when clicked another places

Tags: jquery

I wonder how can i do div box, which when it is clicked then something will happen to the time when we click in some other place. Notice that when we click more than one time in our box nothing special will heppen.

Comment: user jquery

onClick addClass("selected")
check to see if element has class if not add class else do nothing.

how you remove that class that's another question and I'm not sure it's possible without onBlur or some focus reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep a variable to detect whether mouse is inside or in outside,

```
var isIn = false;

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#yourDiv').hover(function(){ 
            isIn =true; 
        }, function(){ 
            isIn =false; 
        });

        $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
            if(isIn) {
               //do your work 
            }else{
              //do your work
          }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#theDiv').one('click', function(){
    $('#theOtherDiv').click(function(){
        alert('I was clicked!');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cpc9s/